# custum beat running error : invalid duration "ns"

Tags: go, elastic-stack

im working on a custum beat that decodes a binary file to extract data and send it to elasticsearch , the complication goes normaly but when i run it, it gives me a running time error of an invalid duration "ns" here is my code:

```
package beater

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math"
    "time"
    //"log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat"
    "github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/common"
    "github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/logp"
    "github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/publisher"

    "github.com/bob96/hc34/config"
)

type Hc34 struct {
    done   chan struct{}

    config config.Config

    client publisher.Client

    siteKey string

    fileKey string

    callEndDateTime string 

    callStartDateTime string

    callerPartyNumber string

    calledPartyNumber string

    incomingTrunkKey string

    outgoingTrunkKey string

    blockNumber string

    blockDateTime string

    headerFunction int

    headerUser int

    callerCategory int

    callerOrigineIdentity string

    complementaryIdentity string 

    calledDigits string 

    traficType int 

    serviceType int 

    supportService int 

    chargeDuration int 

    chargeMeters int 

    outgoingTrunk string

    reserved string 

    operatorIdentity string

    operatorServiceType string

    block string

    filekey string

    lastIndexTime time.Time
}
// Creates beater
func New(b *beat.Beat, cfg *common.Config) (beat.Beater, error) {
    config := config.DefaultConfig
    if err := cfg.Unpack(&config); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error reading config file: %v", err)
    }

    bt := &Hc34{
        done: make(chan struct{}),
        config: config,
    }
    return bt, nil
}

func (bt *Hc34) Run(b *beat.Beat) error {
    logp.Info("hc34 is running! Hit CTRL-C to stop it.")

    bt.client = b.Publisher.Connect()
    ticker := time.NewTicker(bt.config.Period) 
    //counter := 1
    for {
        now := time.Now()
        bt.hc34DataHolderfunc(bt.config.Path) 
        bt.lastIndexTime = now             
        logp.Info("Event sent")
        select {
        case <-bt.done:
            return nil
        case <-ticker.C:
        }

        /*event := common.MapStr{
            "@timestamp": common.Time(time.Now()),
            "type":       b.Name,
            "counter":    counter,
        }
        bt.client.PublishEvent(event)
        logp.Info("Event sent")
        counter++*/
    }
}

func (bt *Hc34) Stop() {
    bt.client.Close()
    close(bt.done)
}
//checking error
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func (bt *Hc34) hc34DataHolderfunc(dirfile string) {    
//reading the binary file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(dirfile)
    check(err)
    //t := f.ModTime() 
    bt.hc34decoderfunc(string(data))

    event := common.MapStr{
            "@timestamp": common.Time(time.Now()),
            /*"siteKey": siteKey,
            "fileKey": fileKey,*/
            //"callEndDateTime":    bt.callEndDateTime,
            //"callStartDateTime": bt.callStartDateTime,
            "callerPartyNumber": bt.callerPartyNumber,
            "calledPartyNumber": bt.calledPartyNumber,
            //"incomingTrunkKey": bt.incomingTrunkKey,
            //"outgoingTrunkKey": bt.outgoingTrunkKey,
            "blockNumber": bt.blockNumber,
            "blockDateTime": bt.blockDateTime,
            "headerFunction": bt.headerFunction,
            "headerUser": bt.headerUser,
            "callerCategory": bt.callerCategory,
            "callerOrigineIdentity": bt.callerOrigineIdentity,
            "complementaryIdentity": bt.complementaryIdentity,
            "calledDigits": bt.calledDigits,
            "traficType": bt.traficType,
            "serviceType": bt.serviceType,
            "supportService": bt.supportService,
            "chargeDuration": bt.chargeDuration,
            "chargeMeters": bt.chargeMeters,
            //"outgoingTrunk": bt.outgoingTrunk,
            "reserved": bt.reserved,
            "peratorIdentity": bt.operatorIdentity,
            "operatorServiceType": bt.operatorServiceType,
        }
            bt.client.PublishEvent(event)


}
type hc34decoder struct{
    block string
    siteKey string
    filekey string
}
func (bt *Hc34) hc34decoderfunc(block string){
    // Get header (32 bytes) and content (1932 bytes) from block

    header :=block[0:64]
    content :=block[64:len(block)]
    // Get block key and date time from header
    blockKey :=header[4:10]
    yearBlock :=header[10:12]
    //BDTdecode, err := hex.DecodeString(header[10:12])

    bt.blockDateTime =bt.getDate(bt.getDateBlockHeader(header[10:22]))
    /*if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }*/
    // process content to extract CDRs
    start := 0
    totalCdr := len(content) / 84
    for z := 0; z < totalCdr; z++ {
        record := content[start:start + 84]
        start = start + 84
        // Extract data from single record
        //CEDdecode, err :=hex.DecodeString(record[10:12])
        a:= hex2decimal(record[54:56])
        headerFunction:= hex2decimal(record[0:2])
        headerUser:= hex2decimal(record[2:4])
        callerCategory:= hex2decimal(record[4:6])
        callEndDateTime :=bt.getDate(bt.getDateCall(record[6:16], yearBlock))
        callerOrigineIdentity:= strings.Replace(string(record[16:26]),"F","",-1)
        complementaryIdentity := strings.Replace(string(record[26:36]),"F","",-1)
        calledDigits:= strings.Replace(string(record[36:54]),"F","",-1)
        traficType:= hex2decimal(strings.Replace(string(a),"F","",-1))
        serviceType := hex2decimal(record[56:58])
        supportService :=hex2decimal(record[58:60])
        duration :=hex2decimal(record[60:64])
        meters:= hex2decimal(record[64:70])
        //outgoingTrunk :=strings.Replace(string(record[70:74]),"F", "",-1)
        bt.reserved = record[74:78]
        bt.operatorIdentity = strings.Replace(string(record[78:82]),"F", "",-1)
        bt.operatorServiceType =record[82:84]
        bt.blockNumber=blockKey
        bt.callerPartyNumber = bt.getFormattedMsisdnHc34Caller(complementaryIdentity, callerOrigineIdentity)
        bt.calledPartyNumber = bt.getFormattedMsisdnHc34Called(calledDigits)

        bt.callStartDateTime  = bt.getStartDate(callEndDateTime, int(duration) )
        /*if err !=nil{
            log.Fatal(err)
        }*/
        bt.headerFunction=int(headerFunction)
        bt.headerUser=int(headerUser)
        bt.callerCategory=int(callerCategory)
        bt.traficType=int(traficType)
        bt.serviceType=int(serviceType)
        bt.supportService=int(supportService)
        bt.chargeMeters=int(meters)
        bt.chargeDuration=int(duration)

func (bt *Hc34) getStartDate(endTime string, duration int) string{
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, endTime)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    return (t.Add(time.Duration(-duration) * time.Second)).String()

}
/**
     * Get the date of the call.
     * @param input the quanted date
     * @param year the year
     * @return the date of the call
     */
func (bt *Hc34) getDateCall(input string,year string) string{
        quant:= hex2decimal(input[1:4])
        hour := input[4:len(input)]

        return "20" + year + bt.getQuantDate(quant) + "" + hour
    }

    /**
     * Get date of block header.
     * @param input the quanted date
     * @return the date block header
     */
func(bt *Hc34) getDateBlockHeader(input string) string{
        year := input[0:2]
        quant:= hex2decimal(input[3:6])
        hour := input[6:len(input)];
        /*if err!=nil{
            panic(err)
        }*/
        return "20" + year + bt.getQuantDate(quant) + "" + hour
    }

    /**
     * format date.
     * @param date the date
     * @return the formatted date
     */

func(bt *Hc34) getDate(date string) string{
        year := date[0:4]
        month := date[4:6]
        day := date[6:8]
        hour := date[8:10]
        minute := date[10:12]
        second := date[12:14]
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    }
     /**
     * Format quanted date.
     * @param quant the quanted date
     * @return the formatted date
     */
func(bt *Hc34) getQuantDate(quant int) string{
        nanoDayOfYear:=string(quant*24*60*60*1000*1000*1000) + "ns"
        durt,err:=time.ParseDuration(nanoDayOfYear)
        t := time.Date(2009, time.January, 01, 00, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
        t=t.Add(durt)
        if err!=nil{

            panic(err)
        }
        return string(t.Month())+""+string(t.Day())

    }
func bin(i int, prefix bool) string {
      i64 := int64(i)

      if prefix {
              return "0b" + strconv.FormatInt(i64, 2) // base 2 for binary
      } else {
              return strconv.FormatInt(i64, 2) // base 2 for binary
      }
}

func bin2int(binStr string) int {

// base 2 for binary
result, _ := strconv.ParseInt(binStr, 2, 64)
return int(result)
}


func hex(i int, prefix bool) string {
  i64 := int64(i)

  if prefix {
          return "0x" + strconv.FormatInt(i64, 16) // base 16 for hexadecimal
  } else {
          return strconv.FormatInt(i64, 16) // base 16 for hexadecimal
  }
}

func hex2int(hexStr string) int {
  // base 16 for hexadecimal
  result, _ := strconv.ParseInt(hexStr, 16, 64)
  return int(result)
}
func hex2decimal(hexStr string) int{

    base16 := 16;

    var val float64
    for i:=0; i>len(hexStr);i++{
        vala:=hex2int(string(base16))
        valo:=hex2int(string(hexStr[len(hexStr)-i]))
        val+=float64(valo)*math.Pow(float64(vala),float64(i))
    }
    return int(val)

}
```

and here its the error that i have :

```
panic: time: invalid duration ns

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/bob96/hc34/beater.(*Hc34).getQuantDate(0xc42012a8c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/beater/hc34.go:354 +0x2cf
github.com/bob96/hc34/beater.(*Hc34).getDateBlockHeader(0xc42012a8c0, 0xc4202d000a, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/beater/hc34.go:324 +0x73
github.com/bob96/hc34/beater.(*Hc34).hc34decoderfunc(0xc42012a8c0, 0xc4202d0000, 0x2d128)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/beater/hc34.go:190 +0x77
github.com/bob96/hc34/beater.(*Hc34).hc34DataHolderfunc(0xc42012a8c0, 0xc420103140, 0x5e)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/beater/hc34.go:141 +0xd3
github.com/bob96/hc34/beater.(*Hc34).Run(0xc42012a8c0, 0xc420142420, 0xc4201424c8, 0xb)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/beater/hc34.go:105 +0x109
github.com/bob96/hc34/vendor/github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat.(*Beat).launch(0xc420142420, 0x9a84c8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/vendor/github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat/beat.go:211 +0x706
github.com/bob96/hc34/vendor/github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat.Run(0x9855d5, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9a84c8, 0xc4200001a0, 0xc4200001a0)
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/vendor/github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat/beat.go:136 +0x65
main.main()
    /home/hp/src/github.com/bob96/hc34/main.go:12 +0x54
```

what i thought in the first place is that the date functions don't get any string from the file, because we can't have a duration type "ns" but we need to have an integer before "ns" like so : "500ns".

sorry if i put out all the code i just didn't understand where exectly is my problem.

thanks for helping me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line looks problematic:

```
nanoDayOfYear:=string(quant*24*60*60*1000*1000*1000) + "ns"
```

Specifically, `string(...)` doesn't do what you want. Presumably you want to convert that number to a base-10 string. Try this instead:

```
nanoDayOfYear:=strconv.FormatInt(quant*24*60*60*1000*1000*1000, 10) + "ns"
```

Comment: it works but i have a new error slice bounds out of range, can you tell me how to found where is the problem in a runtime error type of errors, because i'm confused where to found the problem.

Comment: If this answered the question, please mark it as an answer. If you have a new question, please post it as such (if you haven't already). Adding on new questions in comments just makes this question less helpful for future visitors.